# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'foroshande' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['foroshande/(?P<prof_id>[^/]+)$']

Tags: python, django, backend

idk what to do with this. looks like i need to pass `prof_id` in **home** but **i dont need an id in my url this is home**

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import *
    from .forms import *
    
    
    def home(request):
        form = DatasetForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'form': form})
    
    
    def foroshande(request, prof_id):
        prof = DatasetModel.objects.get(pk=prof_id)
        return render(request, 'main/foroshande.html', {'prof': prof})
```

home.html

```
 {% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'foroshande' prof.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="save"  />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

foroshande.html

```
 {% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ prof }}
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models


    class DatasetModel(models.Model):
        open_or_close_CHOICES = (
            ("baaz", "baaz"),
            ("basteh", "basteh")
        )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        open_or_close = models.CharField(
            max_length=20,
            choices=open_or_close_CHOICES,
            default="baaz"
        )
```

forms.py

```
class DatasetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DatasetModel
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'open_or_close']
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from main import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('foroshande/<prof_id>', views.foroshande, name='foroshande'),
```

idk what to do with this. looks like i need to pass `prof_id` in **home** but **i dont need an id in my url this is home**

Comment: can you provide the content of urls.py ?

Comment: Probably made mistake in ``urls.py``

Comment: form.id is emty in your url tag in home.html